# HorizontalScrollView in RecycleView scrollRight at the beginning

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, horizontalscrollview

I'm trying to use HorizontalScrollView in recycle view, so each item will have all his data inside, and i'm trying to start it all the way right. but not matter what i'm trying, i still see the left side of scroll view for few milliseconds before it scroll itself to end

my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


    <com.cobox.core.ui.views.CustomHorizontalScollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/horizontal_scroll_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="none">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/view_home_card_and_button_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:background="@color/amber_200" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cardView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/half_unit"
            app:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


    </LinearLayout>

</com.cobox.core.ui.views.CustomHorizontalScollView>
```

The scrollView:

```
public class CustomHorizontalScollView extends HorizontalScrollView {

    public OnScrollChangedListener mOnScrollChangedListener;

    public CustomHorizontalScollView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomHorizontalScollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

    }

    public CustomHorizontalScollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
        super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
        if (mOnScrollChangedListener != null) {
            mOnScrollChangedListener.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
        }
    }

    public void setOnScrollChangedListener(OnScrollChangedListener onScrollChangedListener) {
        this.mOnScrollChangedListener = onScrollChangedListener;
    }

    public interface OnScrollChangedListener {
        void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt);
    }

}
```

and the relevant part on code:

```
public class HomeScreenCardView extends FrameLayout implements 
HomeCardActionsListener {
public HomeScreenCardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    this.context = context;


    init(attrs, defStyle);
}

...
private void init(AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {

    WindowManager wm = ((Activity) context).getWindowManager();
    Display d = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams2 = mCardView.getLayoutParams();
    float dip = 8f;
    float px = getPxFromDp(dip);
    layoutParams2.width = (int) (d.getWidth() - px * 2);
    mCardView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams2);

    horizontalScrollView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            horizontalScrollView.setSmoothScrollingEnabled(false);
            horizontalScrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_RIGHT);
            horizontalScrollView.setSmoothScrollingEnabled(true);

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**try 
In your java code**

```
horizontalScrollView.setLayoutDirection(View.FOCUS_RIGHT);
```

**and in XML**

**`android:layoutDirection="rtl"`**

Comment: Thats work every second time, the same cell appear first time to the left, next time right, next time left...

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code of scrolling with code below

```
ViewTreeObserver vto = horizontalScrollView.getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener(){
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            horizontalScrollView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            horizontalScrollView.setSmoothScrollingEnabled(false);
            horizontalScrollView.scrollTo(horizontalScrollView.getWidth(), 0);
            horizontalScrollView.setSmoothScrollingEnabled(false);
        }
    });
```